# Problem migrating DB schema after I deleted a table

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I had to change a field in my model from date to integer. Schemamigration could not do this so i had to delete the table (there was no data so it didn't matter). After i made the change I tried to create a new schemamigration to create the new table with the updated field. For some reason schemamigration could not find any changes. I tried to run migrate anyway and it said relation "tablename" does not exist. I tried dbsync but it skips my project. It says i have to use migration.

Any ideas of what to do / what could be causing this issue?

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably still have the old migrations in the `south/` folder. If you anyway start with a new database, you can as well delete the old migrations.

Comment: There are other tables in the database so I wouldn't be able to start with a new database.

Answer (score 0):

- Create the table as before your change.
- Delete the model
- Run schemamigration to create the 'delete table' migration
- Create correct model
- Run schemamigration to create the 'create table' migration
- Apply migrations